# Passing a password to a viewmodel

Tags: c#, security, mvvm, securestring

I've got a project I've been working on that connect to a file server and writes some data to a text file. In order to do this I added a textbox for the user to type their username and a passwordbox well for the password. In my models I have an interface called `IPassword` that looks like the following:

```
public interface IPassword
{
    SecureString Password { get; }
}
```

Using MVVM Light I created a `RelayCommand` and tied it to a button. When the button is clicked it calls the function `ExportList` (I've removed any code relating to my file server location):

```
    public void ExportList(object parameter)
    {
        var passwordContainer = parameter as IPassword;
        NetworkCredential credentials;
        string folder = String.Empty;

        if (passwordContainer != null && IsEnabled == true)
        {
            var securePassword = passwordContainer.Password;
            var password = ConvertToUnsecureString(securePassword);

            credentials = new NetworkCredential();
            credentials.UserName = Username;
            credentials.Password = password;
            credentials.Domain = "domain name";

            folder = "folder location";
            WriteToNetworkFolder(folder, credentials);
        }

        else
        {
            folder = "local folder location";
            WriteToLocalFolder(folder);
        }
    }

    private string ConvertToUnsecureString(SecureString password)
    {
        if (password == null)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        IntPtr unmanagedString = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedString);
        }

        finally
        {
            Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(unmanagedString);
        }
    }

    private void WriteToNetworkFolder(string folder, NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        // Open the connection to the server
        using (new NetworkConnection(folder, credentials))
        {
            foreach (string location in LocationsPicked)
            {
                string fileName = folder + "\\" + location + ".txt";

                // Write out the lines to each text file
                try
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < address.PhysicalAddresses.Count; i++)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(address.PhysicalAddresses[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The file was not written.");
                    Console.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(ioe.StackTrace);
                }
            }

            UpdateStatusBar("Success! Your MAC address(es) were successfully exported!");
        }
    }
```

The main reason I did it this way was because you cannot use databinding to get the password from a passwordbox due to security reasons. Is this the best way to handle this situation? If not, then how would you recommend getting the password?

Comment: *how would you recommend getting the password?* Don't get the password! If you *can* get an actual plain text password to validate against, you've done something wrong.

Comment: Unless you know of a way to login to a file server without a user's credentials I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Is the file server on Active Directory?

Comment: Yes, it also happens to be a domain controller.

Comment: Can't just use Windows auth then?

Comment: Well we still have some computers on our network that have not yet been joined to the domain. If the program was run from one of these computer's wouldn't Windows authentication fail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22433/discussion-between-randomlyknighted-and-mats-mug).

Comment: Isn't this question more appropriate for [StackOverflow.com](http:// StackOverflow.com)?

Comment: My question was meant to be more of a is this the right way to do something than it was a ask for help. To my understanding that is the purpose of Code Review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just use [the overloaded constructor of the `NetworkCredential` class which takes the password as `SecureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783904%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

In this way you can remove the `ConvertToUnsecureString()` method at all and you don't have to read the decrypted value of the password.

---

It is always recommended to use [`System.IO.Path.Combine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) instead of adding up the path by using string concatenation. In this way you will be safe regarding illegal characters in the path, missing `\` etc.